# Drupal 7: How can I display nodes of specific author in a taxonomy term?

Tags: taxonomy-terms

I've a question about taxonomy terms. 
In my organization I've actors that work for me and, for each actor I created a taxonomy term containing some information, such as bio, an image etc.
Each actor can create content of type "post". I want display all contents of a specific actor in his own term.
So, if in actors vocabulary there are "alan", "jack" and "Lucy", whan an user reaches alan term, he can see all posts created by Alan, and so on.
For security I don't want the actors select terms when create posts.
I hope you can understand my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I probably wouldn't have used a taxonomy term to store that info, but that's not a big deal.

It sounds like you want a block containing the information in the taxonomy term to appear on a user's post.

You need an entity reference connecting a user/author with the appropriate taxonomy term.

Create View that is based on the taxonomy vocabulary. Use a "contextual reference" starting with the post's node id in the URL to a relationship to the author of the post to another relationship to the taxonomy term using the entity reference.